# RQ Job Terminated Unexpectedly

Tags: python, django, django-rq, rq

I have defined the rq task on module `task.py` as:

```py
import django_rq
import logging
import requests

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def req_call():
    url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response


@django_rq.job('default')
def test_request_call_on_rq_job():
    response = req_call()
    log.warning(f"REQUEST's RESPONSE {response.json()}")
```

When I've offloaded a task in another module as:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':  # rq job test
    log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    test_post_request_on_rq_job.delay()
```

I am getting error as:

```bash
[INFO] *** Listening on default...  [worker:702]
[INFO] default: rq_test_module.tasks.test_request_call_on_rq_job() (676c1945-9e05-4245-aeb2-65100cdb4169)  [worker:875]
[WARNING] Moving job to FailedJobRegistry (Work-horse terminated unexpectedly; waitpid returned 11 (signal 11); )  [worker:1114]
```

I then started doing debugging, then I saw error encounters as soon as the job task tried executing the request call i.e. `requests.get(url)`
And if I remove the request call from the job, then it executed gracefully without any errors.

Signal 11 suggests a segmentation fault, I suspect something related to memory but not quite sure about it.

So anyone here encountered similar issue and workaround for this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the cause of the request being not executed gracefully on rq. I just guess it was due to flow at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/urllib/request.py#L2619 not being able to pick the proxy setting in the RQ context. So I just skipped the way to reach there by setting `NO_PROXY` env to the URL I am trying to request.

Now I can run the request on RQ, as it should be.

But without disabling the proxy it still gives an error, maybe I need to dig more into this.

More context on this:

This seems to problem with MAC OS only, because of the import issue I highlighted above.

OS I am facing this issue: Apple M2 Pro, with OS 13.5 (22G74)

I will post more on this once I find concrete ideas for why it is working by setting `NO_PROXY.

I think I got it :),

Let's set up the this task on `task.py` module
This task imports, underlying MAC os function as I outlined above and you can see exact same call in above link.

```py
def test_mac_import_issue_on_request_lib_task():
    import sys
    if sys.platform == 'darwin':
        from _scproxy import _get_proxy_settings, _get_proxies
        _get_proxy_settings()
        _get_proxies()
```

Then enqueue them from any module, for example

```
if __name__ == '__main__':  # rq job test
    from tasks test_mac_import_issue_on_request_lib_task_on_rq_job
    test_mac_import_issue_on_request_lib_task_on_rq_job.delay()
```

Now run worker & execute your module which trigger this enqueue. Now check, whether it pops the error, for e.g `[WARNING] Moving job to FailedJobRegistry (work-horse terminated unexpectedly; waitpid returned 11)  [worker:874]`

That call was executed normally when you run independently (not in the RQ context),
For e.g in you pyhon shell, if you try running:

```
from _scproxy import _get_proxy_settings, _get_proxies
get_proxy_settings() # This outputs dict
_get_proxy_settings() # This also outputs dict
```

So my next goal is to **find out what's going on in the RQ context**.

I will further update this upon finding more meaningful ideas on this.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.

I'm currently applying the following hack to prevent Python crashes on Mac when issuing a requests.get() from an RQ worker:

```py
import os
os.environ['no_proxy'] = '*'
```

or

```py
def _disable_proxy_for_endpoint(url):
    try:
        # "https://whatever.com/" --> "whatever.com""
        text = url
        if text.endswith('/'):
            text = text[:-1]
        domain = text.split('/')[-1]
        os.environ['NO_PROXY'] = domain
    except:
        pass
```